# Can't set focus on JTextPane inside JavaFX SwingNode

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jtextpane, setfocus

I am trying to set the focus on the JTextPane so that when the window opens it can immediately be edited with the keyboard. However, nothing I've done seems to give the JTextPane focus on startup.  Is this just an issue with using JavaFX with Swing?

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestDialog {

    @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    @FXML
    private SwingNode node;

    private ObservableList<Integer> obsList;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> pane.requestFocusInWindow());
        pane.setText("This issue is not reproducible in JDK 8 early-access build (8u172) which is yet to be released.");

        node.setContent(pane);
         obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int x = 0; x < 12; x++){
            obsList.add(x);
        }
        listView.setItems(obsList);

        node.setFocusTraversable(true);
        node.requestFocus();
        pane.requestFocus();
        pane.grabFocus();
    }

    @FXML
    private void removeItem(ActionEvent event) {
        obsList.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific reason that you need to mix Swing with JavaFX? FX comes with cleaner versions of almost every Swing component so its preferable to use only FX.

Comment: I need to be able to highlight and/or underline specific words and I couldn't find a way to do that in JavaFX without RichTextFX.  I couldn't get RichTextFX to do what I needed so I went with a JTextPane in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now thanks to a solution from [BWC_semaJ](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/9f30g5/cant_set_focus_on_jtextpane_inside_javafx/).  Rather than using:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> pane.requestFocusInWindow());
```

I should have used:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {swingNode.requestFocus();}); //Use this instead
```

Comment: I actually tried commenting out both those lines in my project and it still gives focus to the window when run.

Comment: I double checked and running it any other way begins with the ListView having the focus.  The same goes for when I attempted it in my main program as well.  Any suggestions on reproducing what you did?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want the focus to be on the text so that you can start typing right when the window opens?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to immediately type in the JTextPane after the window comes up.

Comment: That could help though running it with Java 10 doesn't do anything for me either.  The first Test was with 8.  Here are the other two files I used for the test [Test.java](https://pastebin.com/wYTNZQqr) and [TestDialog.fxml](https://pastebin.com/8fvCGJ6t)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but below is the demo program I made based on the sample code and for some reason it works for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class Test extends Application {

    @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    @FXML
    private SwingNode node;

    private ObservableList<Integer> obsList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        initialize(arg0);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(Stage stage){        
        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

        // The program runs the same no matter if one of the below two lines are used or if neither are used
        //SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> pane.requestFocusInWindow());
        //Platform.runLater(() -> {node.requestFocus();});

        pane.setText("This issue is not reproducible in JDK 8 early-access build (8u172) which is yet to be released.");

        node = new SwingNode();
        node.setContent(pane);
        obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for(int x = 0; x < 12; x++){
            obsList.add(x);
        }
        listView = new ListView();
        listView.setItems(obsList);

        node.setFocusTraversable(true);
        node.requestFocus();
        pane.requestFocus();
        pane.grabFocus();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(node);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void removeItem(ActionEvent event) {
        obsList.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's selecting node for focus due to the listView node missing.  When I tried adding the listView to the StackPane it ended up setting focus based on which was added first.